# lzmaライブラリをインポートできません。

Tags: python

## やりたいこと

pandas 0.25.0を使いたいです。
しかし、`pandas`をimportしようとすると、lzmaがインポートできない、というエラーが発生しました。

```
$ pipenv run python -c "import pandas; print(pandas.__version__)"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/share/virtualenvs/annofab-cli-fQbMtggr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import (
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/share/virtualenvs/annofab-cli-fQbMtggr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/api.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper, NamedAgg
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/share/virtualenvs/annofab-cli-fQbMtggr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby.generic import (  # noqa: F401
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/share/virtualenvs/annofab-cli-fQbMtggr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py", line 44, in <module>
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/share/virtualenvs/annofab-cli-fQbMtggr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 88, in <module>
    from pandas.core.generic import NDFrame, _shared_docs
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/share/virtualenvs/annofab-cli-fQbMtggr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 71, in <module>
    from pandas.io.formats.format import DataFrameFormatter, format_percentiles
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/share/virtualenvs/annofab-cli-fQbMtggr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py", line 47, in <module>
    from pandas.io.common import _expand_user, _stringify_path
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/share/virtualenvs/annofab-cli-fQbMtggr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 9, in <module>
    import lzma
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/lzma.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _lzma import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_lzma'
```

## 質問

標準ライブラリ lzmaがimportできないのはなぜでしょうか？
また、どうすれば解決できますか？

```
$ pipenv run python -c "import lzma"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/lzma.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _lzma import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_lzma'
```

`liblzma-dev`をインストールしてから、PyEnvでPython3.7.4をインストールしましたが、importはできませんでした。

```
$sudo apt install liblzma-dev
パッケージリストを読み込んでいます... 完了
依存関係ツリーを作成しています                
状態情報を読み取っています... 完了
liblzma-dev はすでに最新バージョン (5.2.2-1.3) です。
アップグレード: 0 個、新規インストール: 0 個、削除: 0 個、保留: 116 個。
```

## 環境

- python 3.7.4
- pyenv 1.2.8
- pandas 0.25.0
- pipenv 2018.11.26
- ubuntu 18.04
- liblzma-dev 5.2.2-1.3

## 補足

### pyliblzmaのインストール

```
$ pip install pyliblzma
Collecting pyliblzma
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/17/48/5292ade507dafe573360560ba53783395587dc42eb32b347feb2ac70fc6b/pyliblzma-0.5.3.tar.bz2 (43kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 3.2MB/s 
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/bin/python3.7 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-jv1rz7us/pyliblzma/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-jv1rz7us/pyliblzma/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-jv1rz7us/pyliblzma/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-jv1rz7us/pyliblzma/setup.py", line 40, in <module>
        for i in xrange(len(c_files)):
    NameError: name 'xrange' is not defined
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

#### pipのバージョン

```
$ which pip
/home/vagrant/.pyenv/shims/pip
$ pip --version
pip 19.2.1 from /home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
$ type pip
pip はハッシュされています (/home/vagrant/.pyenv/shims/pip)
```

Comment: お使いの `pip` は今使っている仮想環境の Python 3 用ですか？ `pip3` が他にあったり、仮想環境用の `pip` にパスが通ってなかったりしませんか？　`type pip` や `which pip` などで確認してみてください。エラー `NameError: name 'xrange' is not defined` は Python 2/3 の間違いでよく見ます。

Comment: pipのバージョンを追記しました。3.7系のようです。。。

Answer (score 1):

liblzma-devを入れてから、Python仮想環境(3.7.4)をいったん消して作り直す。

Comment: liblzma-dev をインストールしてから PyEnvでPython3.7.4をインストールしましたが、`lzam`をimportできませんでした。

Comment: lzamをimportできませんでした は誤字でしょうか。
tetsu さんの回答で合っていると思います。liblzma-dev がない状態でインストールすると `import lzma` が質問のエラーが発生して失敗し、liblzma-dev をインストールで解消します。

Comment: >lzamをimportできませんでした は誤字でしょうか。
すみません。lzmaの間違いです。

Answer (score 0):

以下のプロセスに従ってください

```
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
$ export LC_ALL=C
$ sudo pip install pipenv
$ pipenv run python -c "import lzma"
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

$ pipenv run python3.7 -c "import lzma"
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/lzma.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _lzma import *
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_lzma'

$ sudo apt-get install python-lzma
$ pip3.7 install pyliblzma

# if not works, try
$ sudo apt install libssl-dev libncurses5-dev libsqlite3-dev libreadline-dev libtk8.5 libgdm-dev libdb4o-cil-dev libpcap-dev
$ cd ~/<path>/Python3.7
$ sudo ./configure
$ sudo make
$ sudo make install

$ cat cat test.py
import lzma
data = b"Insert Data Here"
    with lzma.open("file.xz", "w") as f:
    f.write(data)
$ pipenv run python3.7 test.py
$ $ strings file.xz
7zXZ
Insert Data Here
```

Comment: pyliblzmaをインストールするのはなぜでしょうか？lzmaは標準ライブラリなので、サードパーティのライブラリは不要だと考えています。